# Prolog: Shifting text left and right on the keyboard

Tags: autocomplete, keyboard, prolog, levenshtein-distance

I want to write a Prolog predicate that takes a word and *shifts* it left or right on the keyboard...

..., but—so far—I do not have a *clue* where to start from.

---

**Example.** Let's shift the word "loogika" to the left on a [qwerty](/questions/tagged/qwerty) keyboard!

Note that, if our [keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout) is [qwerty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY),
we hit an *edge* when left-shifting <kbd>a</kbd>. We *can* deal with that in 
different ways, but it appears that *each* "solution" has its own and up- *and* down-sides.

So what do we do? Let left-shifted <kbd>a</kbd> *not* be <kbd>Caps [**Lock**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_key)</kbd>, but rather stay <kbd>a</kbd>. IMO, *not* toggling that nasty <kbd>Caps-Lock</kbd> **is** worth losing algebraic properties, which are hard to uphold when 
handling other edge/corner cases in a way that preserves the 2D physical distances... YMMV!

Sample Prolog query:

```
?- tipi([l,o,o,g,i,k,a],
        [k,i,i, f,u,j,a]).
true.
```

Which keys get pressed when we write "loogika" / "kiifuja" on qwerty keyboards? Look and see!

[image: before and after shift left, animated]

Comment: Please post some example input and expected results - positive and negative.

Comment: @repeat does my answer, answer your bounty question?

Answer (score 1):

For the original question:

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).

table([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p], [a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,;],[z,x,c,v,b,n,m,',','.','/']]).

shift_left(Char,New_Char):-
  table(Table),
  member(R,Table),
  nth1(I,R,Char),
  shift_l(I,NI),
  nth1(NI,R,New_Char).

shift_right(Char,New_Char):-
  table(Table),
  member(R,Table),
  nth1(I,R,Char),
  shift_r(I,NI),
  nth1(NI,R,New_Char).

shift_seq(left,Seq,NewSeq):-
  maplist(shift_left,Seq,NewSeq).
shift_seq(right,Seq,NewSeq):-
  maplist(shift_right,Seq,NewSeq).

shift_l(1,1).
shift_l(X,Y):-
  X>1,
  X#=Y+1.

shift_r(10,10).
shift_r(X,Y):-
  X<10,
  X#=Y-1.
```

Query:

```
?- shift_seq(left,[l,o,o,g,i,k,a],N).
N = [k, i, i, f, u, j, a] .
```

I assume the g in the question is a typo ;)

For the bounty, you could use the Manhattan distance in this table. And then combine that distance with a weight to the Levenshtein distance. I came up with the following adaptation. I am not sure if it is a 'real distance function'.

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).
:-use_module(library(aggregate)).

table([['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'],[q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p], [a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,;],[z,x,c,v,b,n,m,',','.','/']]).

vert_distance(A,B,Table,Distance):-
  length(Table,L),
  Distance in 0..L,
  member(Row1,Table),
  member(Row2,Table),
  member(A,Row1),
  member(B,Row2),
  nth0(N1,Table,Row1),
  nth0(N2,Table,Row2),
  Distance #= abs(N1-N2).

hoz_distance(A,B,Table,Distance):-
  member(Row1,Table),
  member(Row2,Table),
  length(Row1,L),
  Distance in 0..L,
  nth0(N1,Row1,A),
  nth0(N2,Row2,B),
  Distance #= abs(N1-N2).

manhatten(A,B,Table,D):-
  vert_distance(A,B,Table,V),
  hoz_distance(A,B,Table,H),
  D#=V+H.

manhatten_string([],[],_,0).
manhatten_string(String1,String2,Table,D):-
  length(String1,L),
  length(String2,L),
  manhatten_string_(String1,String2,Table,D1),
  D is D1/L.
manhatten_string(S1,S2,Table,D):-
  length(S1,L1),
  length(S2,L2),
  D#=abs(L1-L2).

manhatten_string_([],[],_,0).
manhatten_string_(String1,String2,Table,D1):-
  String1 =[H1|T1],
  String2 =[H2|T2],
  manhatten(H1,H2,Table,DL),
  manhatten_string(T1,T2,Table,D0),
  D1 is D0+(DL/14).

lev(String1,String2,D):-
  length(String1,L1),
  length(String2,L2),
  0 is min(L1,L2),
  D is max(L1,L2).
lev(String1,String2,D):-
  String1 =[H1|T1],
  String2 =[H2|T2],
  lev(T1,String2,D1),
  lev(String1,T2,D2),
  lev(T1,T2,D3),
  D1plus1 is D1+1,
  D2plus1 is D2+1,
  indicator([H1],[H2],DM),
  D3plus is D3+DM,
  aggregate_all(min(X),member(X,[D1plus1,D2plus1,D3plus]),D).

indicator(Ai,Bj,0):-
  Ai=Bj.
indicator(Ai,Bj,D):-
  Ai\=Bj,
  table(Table),
  manhatten_string(Ai,Bj,Table,D).
```

Queries:

```
?- lev([a,a],[b,a],D).
D = 0.35714285714285715 .

?- lev([a,a],[a,b],D).
D = 0.35714285714285715 .

?- lev([a,a],[a,b,c,d],D).
D = 2.142857142857143 .

?- lev([a],[],D).
D = 1 .

?- lev([a],[s],D).
D = 0.07142857142857142 .

?- lev([a],[o],D).
D = 0.6428571428571429 .

?- lev([a,b],[a,b],D).
D = 0 .

?- lev([a,b,c],[a,b],D).
D = 1 .

?- lev([a,b,c],[a,b,p],D).
D = 0.6428571428571429 .
```

There is also library(isub) http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(0,%270%27,swi(%27/doc/packages/nlp.html%27)). Which looks appropriate for part of this.